# How to create array for params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails controller I'm getting JSON posted to it that contains a person's work history.  So they could have multiple jobs.  The jobs are in a format like...

```
"values": 
[
  {
    "title": "dummy position",
    "company": "company 1",
    "location": "Indianapolis, IN",
    "description": "dummy job description",
    "startDateMonth": "05",
    "startDateYear": "2015",
    "endDateMonth": "06",
    "endDateYear": "2015"
  },
  {
    "title": "dummy position 2",
    "company": "company 2",
    "location": "Indianapolis, IN",
    "description": "dummy job description 2",
    "startDateMonth": "02",
    "startDateYear": "2015",
    "endDateMonth": "05",
    "endDateYear": "2015"
  },
  {
    "title": "dummy position 3",
    "company": "company 3",
    "location": "Indianapolis, IN",
    "description": "dummy job description 3",
    "startDateMonth": "05",
    "startDateYear": "2013",
    "endDateMonth": "02",
    "endDateYear": "2015"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to add these to the params collection that I can later iterate through in an application class and add these work histories.  I have the following code but it doesn't work - NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass: for this line params[:job_title][i] = jobs[i]['title'].  It was just a guess, as I'm not great in ruby, so is there a way to make this work?

```
if job_count.numeric?
  jobs = params['positions']['values']
  for i in 0..job_count.to_i
    params[:job_title][i] = jobs[i]['title']
    params[:job_company_name][i] = jobs[i]['company']
    params[:job_start_date][i] = jobs[i]['startDateMonth'] + '/1/' + jobs[i]['startDateYear']
    params[:job_end_date][i] = jobs[i]['endDateMonth'] + '/1/' + jobs[i]['endDateYear']
    params[:job_description][i] = jobs[i]['description']
  end
end
```

**EDIT: This ended up working.**

```
i = 0
jobs.each do | k, work_history |
  i = i + 1
  params['job_title_' + i.to_s] = work_history['title']
  params['job_company_name_' + i.to_s] = work_history['company']
  params['job_start_date_' + i.to_s] = work_history['startDateMonth'] + '/1/' + work_history['startDateYear']
  params['job_end_date_' + i.to_s] = work_history['endDateMonth'] + '/1/' + work_history['endDateYear']
  params['job_description_' + i.to_s] = work_history['description']
end
```

Comment: The params hash is just what comes in from the post params to the controller.  I can add additional parameters to the hash like params[:new_value] = 'foo' but I'm not sure how to get an array structure in the params hash.

Comment: Because I'm getting JSON posted to my controller action which has a crapload ton of data in it.  Not to be rude, but I don't see how that makes a difference to the question.

Comment: I think I'm close to it but I've found that the Nil class error is happening for jobs[i]['title'] so I'm not referencing it properly. If I do a jobs.inspect I get the following.  "jobtitle{\"0\"=>{\"title\"=>\"dummy position\", \"company\"=>\"company 1\", \"location\"=>\"Indianapolis, IN\", \"description\"=>\"dummy job description\", \"startDateMonth\"=>\"05\", \"startDateYear\"=>\"2015\", \"endDateMonth\"=>\"06\", \"endDateYear\"=>\"2015\"}, \"1\"=>{\"title\"=>\"dummy position 2\".... So the jobs variable has a value.  But how do I iterate through each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because you're trying to do `["title"]` on `nil`, as said, and `jobs[i]` is probably `nil` because `job_count` is wrong.

If you have 3 jobs, and `job_count == 3`, your `for` loop will do 0, 1, 2, 3. However, `jobs[3]` is rightfully nil.

Try replacing that for with `for i in 0..(job_count.to_i - 1)`

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense.  However I already got it figured out a different way.  But thank you.  I'll update my question with what I have that works.